# TTF_OpenFont() returns NULL

Tags: macos, qt, ubuntu, null, sdl-ttf

Here are the facts: I am using codeblocks on Ubuntu. I have installed SDL and SDL_ttf and have  included and linked them successfully. I want to render text to the screen of the font, FreeSerif.

Here is the problem: When the program gets to the line, TTF_OpenFont("FreeSerif.ttf,20"), it returns NULL, which would then cause a segfault if passed to the TTF_RenderText_Solid function. I have added the font file to the project and it still did not work.

Here is the code:
    `TTF_Init();`

```
TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont("FreeSerif.ttf",20); //This returns NULL 

if(!font){printf("Unable to open font");exit(1);} //The program exits here
```

Comment: I am having the same problem but I am using Qt Creator on MacOSX.

Comment: Did you try `TTF_GetError()`? It may say more about the opening error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've had the same problem and it seems to be a path error, TTF_GetError() throw this :

> Couldn't open Arial.ttf

You should set your font with absolute path and not a relative one. For me, it was

> /Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf

instead of :

> Arial.ttf

Comment: Also, it may be copied in the current directory of the executable.

Comment: Sure, but depending on codeblocks (that I don't like at all but that's not the point) settings, the directory of the executable could be hard to determinate, that's why I think that an absolute path may help in diagnostic

Answer (score 4):

You must specify the **full path name**. That, or you must be certain sure that the file is in the current directory for your program (which is not the same as the executable's directory).

So use this instead:

```
TTF_Font *font = TTF_OpenFont("/path/to/FreeSerif.ttf",20);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// load font.ttf at size 20 into font

TTF_Font *font;

font=TTF_OpenFont("font.ttf", 20);

if(!font) {
    printf("TTF_OpenFont: %s\n", TTF_GetError());
   // handle error
}
```

`font.ttf` path not found it return NULL value

`if(!font) not check null value and TTF_GetError()` It returns the last error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Xcode 15.2 and I encountered this problem, and I encountered this problem and spent a whole day figuring out what's wrong. I've tried the absolute path, relative path, reinstalling SDL and just about everything I thought of, and then I went to the build phases, copy bundle resources and add the font file there for everyone who encounters the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but try to keep your answer to the point, i.e. explain how you solved the problem (and not how much time you have spent and/or all the tried solutions that don't work).