# TTF_OpenFont returning NULL

Tags: c++, sdl, truetype, sdl-ttf

[TTF_OpenFont() returns NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043437/ttf-openfont-returns-null)

I have the same problem, TTF_OpenFont returns NULL and with an error.

```
    TTF_OpenFont("/absolute/path/to/SourceSansPro-Black.ttf", 25);
    std::cout << TTF_GetError() << std::endl;
```

And I get the "**Couldn't load font file**"

- The *.ttf* chmod is 777
- I tried running the program with *root*

I run out of ideas.

Comment: What's the actual path?

Comment: Can you please show the actual code? Where you actually check for the value returned by the function? In other words, can you please make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and edit your question to include that?

Comment: Did you call `TTF_Init`?

Answer (score 5):

*Yes, I had initialized TTF.*

The problem was that I *(don't know how)* was using the older **SDL_TTF** with the **SDL 2.0**

I downloaded the 2.0 TTF, compiled and linked it and now it works.

Comment: For SDL 2.0 the TTF lib should be at least SDL2_ttf 2.0.12 as noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847668/sdl-ttf-cannot-find-sdl-h-but-main-cpp-can/20847799#20847799)

Comment: Thank you! For me on Fedora 20, this meant rebuilding from an SRPM found in [this Bugzilla thread](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1034413) to get the `SDL2_ttf` and `SDL2_ttf-devel` RPMs.

Comment: Just in case this helps anyone else - ***check your linker settings*** - I battled for an hour before I noticed `-lSDL_ttf` instead of `-lSDL2_ttf`.

Answer (score 1):

You can install SDL_TTF for SDL2 in Ubuntu using this:
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-ttf-dev